# Premises for $A \setminus B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find all the possible premises for $A \setminus B = \emptyset$ and so far I have $A \subseteq B$ or $A = \emptyset$ or $A=B$ but I'm not sure if these are ALL the possible premises.

Comment: Isn't $A \setminus B = \emptyset$ simply equivalent to $A \subseteq B$, which includes the other two? This is because $A \setminus B = \{ x \in A : x \notin B \}$, so if this is empty, it means that for all $x \in A$ one has $x \in B$.

Comment: Nvm it is. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\subseteq B$ is equivalent to $A\setminus B = \emptyset$, let's try to prove it.

Being more formal, $A\subseteq B$ means $\forall x \in A$, $x\in B$.

You can deduce from this  that the empty set is a subset of any set. The sentence $\forall x \in \emptyset$, $x\in B$ is true since there are no elements $x\in\emptyset$ to begin with. This means that $A=\emptyset$ is just a case of $A\subseteq B$. It's also true to see that $A=B$ is just a case of $A\subseteq B$. All in all this means that

$$ A\subseteq B\qquad \text{OR} \qquad A=\emptyset\quad  \text{OR} \quad A = B$$
is equivalent to

$$A \subseteq B.$$

Now, you should be able to prove that $$A\subseteq B\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad A\setminus B=\emptyset.$$

As for the premises, well all that imply $A\subseteq B$ are true. So $A=\emptyset$ and $A=B$ are correct.